# I set color to input placeholder in but can't do this for text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want set color for placeholder in input.I write this code for my input

```
 $('#txtEmailForgot').attr('placeholder', function () {
    $(this).css('color', '#6C6C6C');
 });`
```

It works good and when I type the text in input, it must be black but it has the same color like words in placeholder.
How I can set color special for text when I want type something in this input.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try with pure css,

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

This will style all input and textarea placeholders.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/9pEJz/)

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/